# Plotting a line where each segment has different attributes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created an animation in matplotlib which is fundamentally a dot that moves around the grid in a chaotic fashion. The current dot is followed with a tail of its previous N locations. Right now, the tail is plotted in a solid color but what I'd like to do is plot it with each of its N segments having an opacity diminished a little bit from the previous segment such that, at the end of tail, the color has almost faded completely away.

It doesn't appear that the plot function allows multiple colors to be passed to it to be applied in a sequential manner to each segment but, is there another way to accomplish this not involving making separate plot calls for every segment, each with a different opacity setting for the color?

This is the core animation function that is called for every frame. I'm setting the tail to a different color every 10 frames. The colors simply cycle through a range of 5 different colors.

```
def animate(i):
    ip1 = i + 1
    thisx = [0, x1[i], x2[i]]
    thisy = [0, y1[i], y2[i]]
    phi1 = 180.0 * math.atan2(y1[i],x1[i])/math.pi
    phi2 = 180.0 * math.atan2(y2[i],x2[i])/math.pi

    line.set_data(thisx, thisy)

    x = x2[i-1:max(0,i-20):-1]
    y = y2[i-1:max(0,i-20):-1]
    tail.set_data(x, y)

    text = ('\n').join( [
        time_template%(i*dt),
        'Phi 1 = %6.1f deg' % phi1,
        'Phi 2 = %6.1f deg' % phi2 ] )

    time_text.set_text(text)
    if (ip1)%10 == 0:
        tail.set_color(next(g_tail_colors))
    return line, time_text, tail
```

Here is one frame of the animation

[image]

Comment: Please add the code you have so far.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html